# How to lock files to avoid conflicts in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control, merge

We use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and it allows us to check out and edit the same file simultaneously.

We frequently find that we have conflicts, and the merge tool is awful, inserting confusing things like `mine <<<<<<<<<` that is not very helpful.

Is there a way to make VS2010 disallow files from being edited if they're currently being edited by someone else? What about a better merge tool that lets you interactively choose how to merge it, instead of just pasting everything into the file?

Comment: What is your version control system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Subversion as your source control system, understand that it works on an *edit-merge* principal rather than the exclusive check-out model employed by tools like Visual SourceSafe. That means everyone can edit their working copies at the same time, and differences should be resolved by developers as they perform regular updates to their working copies. So, doing what you're asking runs a bit against the grain for how Subversion was designed to work.

That said, however, you can come fairly close to the SourceSafe check-out notion by "locking" a file. If you're using something like the Ankh Plug In for Visual Studio, you can right-click on a file in the Solution Explorer and choose "Lock."

You can also set a property on a file called "svn:needs-lock" which means that if you get a working copy of a file, its delivered read-only, and if you want to edit it, you must explicitly lock it.

**EDIT**: For a quick rundown of the Subversion locking philosophy, you might take a look [here.](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks, that distinction wasn't clear to me. I guess that what I really want is either to move to a check-out model or I want to get a better merge tool. If the Subversion model is edit-merge, the merge part of that sure sucks. Is there a way to improve it, or should I just look into getting something like SourceSafe?

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is computable, do NOT get SourceSafe. Everything about it is old, broken, and evil.

Comment: Greg, what _would_ you recommend?

Comment: Subversion is still a reasonable choice, but for the best tool today I would recommend Git or Mercurial. However, like any tool you will have to learn about how they work, and by default all three tools I've mentioned handle merge conflicts the same way.

Comment: Brent, I would surely second the notion of staying away from SourceSafe. If you have good communication on your team, you should be able to avoid most if not all the situations in which you would find yourself imposing drastically conflicting edits on the same files that would require draconian steps to resolve. Also, be aware that there are multiple merge tools available - if you have the TortoiseSVN Subversion shell extension for Windows, TortoiseMerge can be used as an external merge tool through the AnkhSVN plug-in for Visual Studio. That's just one example.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using Subversion correctly. The fact that you would mention that `mine <<<<<<` pattern used by SVN in conflict files tells me you're probably better off taking a couple of Subversion classes rather than trying to figure out how to lock files.

Comment: I don't think any colleges in my town offer night classes on subversion.

Comment: I know, that was more tongue-in-cheek than anything else. You _do_ have that problem though, there are a LOT of [online resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=subversion+tutorial) that can help you. Good luck.